# How iOS app get IMEI and other device's information from MDM server?

Tags: ios, swift, mdm, imei

Our team already create a MDM server, and get the device's information after it register to MDM server.
But now the problem is: how can I get the device's information (like IMEI) back to our application(app)?

I've search some method, that mention MDM server can 'push' a dictionary to the app's NSUserDefaults container. How does this work?

I'm really new to this field :( Please give me some hints, Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to send a device information query - See page 36 in the [MDM protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf). To get the information you want you need to ensure that your initial MDM payload you installed on the device has the "Allow query of network information" access right

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, Thanks for reply! Actually, our MDM server can get the device's information already~ But what I want is let MDM server bring the device's information back to our app. Because app can't get the information(like IMEI) through api or SDK. That's why we want to find method to let MDM server send IMEI back to our app.

Comment: Well that is entirely in your hands.  You would need to create some API for your MDM server that lets your app query its database.  Your challenge will be identifying the device that is making the call in relation to the device in your MDM database.

Comment: @Paulw11 This is one of the road we are trying, since app can only get information like device name, available space of this device. Then we can use those data mapping which the device is on MDM server. However, this method may come through some risk if there are two devices with the same name and available space(new device).

Comment: If you use an app to perform the enrolment then your app can send `identifierForVendor` when it performs the enrolment. Other apps that you publish will get the same `identifierForVendor` value on that device.

Comment: You can fill with MDM managed apps UserDefaults. You can send on every device unique identifier into UserDefaults. Your's app will use it to identify self on your's server.

Comment: You can install configuration profile with unique authentication certificate for every device, then you will be able to protect calls to the server and identify device with it

Comment: Hi @Inyouchange, can you share the doc about the "push a dictionary to the app's NSUserDefaults container"? I want to find some ways to manage the other apps' behavior.